# "rectifyStereoImages" in MATLAB not working

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, matlab-cvst, stereo-3d

I am working in the Stereo Vision for the first time. I am trying to rectify the stereoImages. The following is the result
[image]

I can't understand why the image is getting cropped

The following is my code

```
% Read in the stereo pair of images.
I1 = imread('sceneReconstructionLeft.jpg');
I2 = imread('sceneReconstructionRight.jpg');

% Rectify the images.
[J1, J2] = rectifyStereoImages(I1, I2, stereoParams);

% Display the images before rectification.
figure;
imshow(stereoAnaglyph(I1, I2), 'InitialMagnification', 50);
title('Before Rectification');

% Display the images after rectification.
figure;
imshow(stereoAnaglyph(J1, J2), 'InitialMagnification', 50);
title('After Rectification');
```

I am trying to follow this guide

http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/stereo-calibration-and-scene-reconstruction.html

The images I used

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the images so we can try?

Comment: I have added the images

Comment: Can you also add `stereoParams`? We cannot run your code!

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C40D099C26112354!1021&authkey=!AIjYPmxq9kz5qDk&ithint=file%2cmat

Comment: stereoParams is in the variable

Comment: You stereoPArams must be wrong, cant find another answer.

Comment: I will try the calibration again

Comment: I did the calibration again. But the result is the same. These are the new files

http://1drv.ms/1HxnFQY

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82120/discussion-between-kenneth-roy-and-ander-biguri).

Comment: The calibration is not wrong. The baseline is too wide or the objects are too close.

Comment: I am doing stereo for the first time. What do you mean by baseline is too wide?

Comment: Baseline is the distance between your cameras.  You need wider baseline to be able to measure things further away. But then you can't measure things that are too close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing the following:

```
[J1, J2] = rectifyStereoImages(I1, I2, stereoParams, 'OutputView', 'Full');
```

This way you will see the entire images. 
[image]

By default, `rectifyStereoImages` crops the output images to only contain the overlap between the two frames. In this case the overlap is very small compared to the disparity.

What is happening here is that the baseline (distance between the cameras) is too wide, and the distance to the objects is too short. This results in a very large disparity, which will be hard to compute reliably. I suggest that you either move the cameras closer together, or move the cameras further away from the objects of interest, or both.

Comment: I checked it. I1 was taken by the left camera itself

Comment: Thanks for posting your images. I have updated the answer.

Comment: i did that. Now I can see the entire image. But it is not properly rectified as shown in the tutorial

http://1drv.ms/1HvgXck

Comment: That's strange.  As you can see, I have a reasonable-looking rectification from the images you've posted. Try swapping I1 and I2.

Comment: Oh you are right. They are rectified. I thought they will also overlap each other as shown in the guide

Comment: "Rectified" means that the epipolar lines are horizontal, and the corresponding points are on the same pixel row.  How much overlap you get depends on the baseline and orientation of the cameras.